# iOS : CGContextStrokePath(context) crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios12, catiledlayer

I am trying to draw a signature using `CALayer` with `CGContextStrokePath(context)` but it's crashing with tricky crash with below error in iOS 12 only:

> malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x1196538c8: probably
>   modified after being freed.
>       Corrupt value: 0x4069e00000000000
>       (899,0x17190b000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Code Snippet:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CATiledLayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)contx {
    if (layer == canvasLayer) {
        //we don't want this to fire after the background layer update
        //and after the path has been released
        if (!touching) return;
        CGContextAddPath(contx, path);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(contx, 7.0f);
        CGContextStrokePath(contx);
    }
    else if (layer == bckLayer) {
        CGContextSaveGState(contx);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(contx, 0, backgroundLayer.bounds.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(contx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGImageRef ref = cacheImage.CGImage;
        CGContextDrawImage(contx, backgroundLayer.bounds, ref);
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message says "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug". Have you tried it? Also, what is the stack trace of the crash? Do you access CALayer objects from backtround threads? - If you have problems with one of these steps, let me know..

Comment: I would highly suspect `path` here. It looks like a direct ivar access, and is probably under-retained (which is why I recommend using accessors rather than messing with your ivars directly, which this code seems to do a lot…)

Comment: Yeah, that would be bad. It would mean that the OP is using manually memory managed code (non-ARC). Because with ARC, the iVars should be retained/released when changed.

Comment: @Michael, Please look into stack trace here https://imgur.com/QR5KtV7

Comment: @Michael more detailed backtrace is here https://imgur.com/a/vvNHNCq

Comment: @SRK: are you using ARC? The other thing is that I don't see how your code is calling CFRelease. According to the backtrace it is. I suspect that one or more stack frames have been optimized away (there is nothing you can do about it, btw.) Can you see at which line in your code the app is crashing? If not, can you put a few NSLog-messages there? One at the start of the method, one at the start of each block (the if and the else if), and one at the end of the method (they all have to print something different, so we know what's going on)? Also, set a symbolic breakpoint to malloc_error_break..